# Detect if a media (video or audio) is playing on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on App that uses Airplay. As part of the requirements, I need to detect if a video is playing on the device to stop the Airplay streaming.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

[isOtherAudioPlaying](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616610-isotheraudioplaying)

> A Boolean value that indicates whether another app is playing audio.

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().isOtherAudioPlaying
```

or

[secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616600-secondaryaudioshouldbesilencedhi)

> A Boolean value that indicates whether another application is playing audio.

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint
```

Comment: Thanks omerfarukozturk, is there a similar functionality for video?